# Why I am getting 500 (Internal Server Error) in Struts 2 while sending data using Ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2, http-status-code-500

I am trying to develop a struts 2 web application and sending data via Ajax but the console show an  **500 (Internal Server Error)**. I have tried a log but no solution found. 
But the operation performed successfully in back end means my data is updated but the output is   **Internal Server Error**
 Here is my code..

ajax function

```
   function revertIbcData(mydata) {
            var paNo = $(mydata).attr("rollNo");
            var viNo = $(mydata).attr("idNo");
            alert(paNo + " " + viNo);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json;  charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                url: "revert.do",
                data: {rollNo: paNo, idNo: viNo},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.msg);
                },
                error: function (abc, cba, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

action code

```
    public String revertData() {
    try {
        conn = connect.getConnection();
        ibcDAO.revertIbcProcessDetail(conn, rollNo, idNo);
        msg = "Detail of " + rollNo + " and " + idNo + " reverted successfully.";
        System.out.println(msg);
        return "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "success";
    } 
}
```

and struts.xml is

```
    <action name="revert"  class="pac.ProcessAction" method="revertData">
        <result name="success" type="json"></result>                   
    </action>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the server logs?  There is most likely a log message (hopefully with a stack trace) that says what went wrong.  Note that the 500 response code comes from the server, so something **on the server side** should know what the problem is.

Comment: did you try to stringify the request data?

Comment: @Bindrid: yes i have tired stringify but getting same result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<action name="revert"  class="pac.ProcessAction" method="revertData">
       <result name="success" type="json">
         <param name="root">jsonString</param>
       </result>                   
    </action>
```

Here "jsonString" should be a class level variable.

Answer (score 0):

Set log inside revertData to determine where error occurs, and check this article: http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/read-json-object-from-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/